# Is it possible to monitor the sum of squared errors in a NonlinearModelFit or FindFit procedure during the process?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, monitoring

Since fitting procedures using `NonlinearModelFit` (or `FindFit`) sometimes take very long, I would like to monitor the sum of squared errors *during* the process (seeing it afterwards is well documented). Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps the `StepMonitor` or `EvaluationMonitor` options, and calculate the error in the function you associate with it, printing/sowing/monitoring as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a trivial example of the method in my comment. I've used total absolute difference for error (you can use whatever you please), and I put in a `Pause` so you can observe the effect for this trivial problem that would be blink-of-an-eye fast. In reality, you'd want to use `UpdateInterval` or equivalent, or `Sow` if you want the "history" post-run. Doing anything like this will of course increase run-times I'm sure I need not say.

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

Monitor[nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x,
   StepMonitor :> (mon = 
      Abs[Log[a + b #^2] & /@ data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]] // 
        Total]; Pause[.5])], mon]
```

Answer (score 8):

Expanding a little over rasher's answer:

```
data = Table[{x, Log[3.5 + 2.5 x^2] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 10}];
r = {}; s = {}; u = {};
Dynamic[
 GraphicsGrid[{{
    Plot[Log[r[[-1]] + s[[-1]] x^2], {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]}, 
         PlotLabel -> "Fitting", Frame -> True, 
         Epilog :> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}, PlotRangePadding -> 2],
    ListLinePlot[{r, s}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b"}, Above], 
                 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
    ListLogPlot[u, Joined -> True, PlotLabel -> "Absolute error", 
                Frame -> True]}}, Spacings -> 100]]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
      StepMonitor :> (AppendTo[r, a]; AppendTo[s, b];
                     AppendTo[u, Abs[Log[a + b #^2] & /@ data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]] // 
                     Total]]; Pause[1])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @rasher We were working in parallel :) +1 to you too

Comment: Thanks a lot Rasher and Belisarius! I really appreciate your help.