# Dynamic Syntax - Evaluate AppendTo as the second argument

Tags: dynamic

I am attempting to `Append` a new value into my list `paramMonitor` whenever the value for `B` changes. I had the code working perfectly, but my computer crashed without saving the document. I am now having a lot of trouble (dynamically) appending these values to my list.

My attempts:

- This updates `B` but does nothing to append the value {`B`, `e`, `some number`} to `paramMonitor`

  ```
  Dynamic[B,  
          AppendTo[paramMonitor, 
            {B,e,Abs[model[B, e][#] & /@ test[[All, 1]] - test[[All, 2]]] // Total}]
  ```

and

- Removing the first argument 'B', this code fails to compile and simply aborts upon execution:

  ```
  Dynamic[AppendTo[paramMonitor, 
           {B,e, Abs[model[B, e][#] & /@ test[[All, 1]] - etst[[All, 2]]] // Total}]
  ```

I believe this is a quick fix (since I had it working earlier), but I cannot seem to find the issue.

Comment: Before I will update the answer, please tell me how `B` can be changed? I mean, it is tied to some kind of controller or it is just a global variable that can be change anywhere?

Comment: Sorry about the late response. B is changed through NonLinearModelFit (NLMF). NLMF is finding the best fit values for B and e.
I have NLMF's EvaluationMonitor printing "B and e values" to the screen. So, at every new evaluation step, Dynamic[B] will update.

Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: So my answer does not fit your needs quite well, right?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since NonlinearModel takes a very long time to evaluate, I wanted a way to monitor its progress in Real-Time. My other option is to add some commands within EvaluationMonitor, like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41264/is-it-possible-to-monitor-the-sum-of-squared-errors-in-a-nonlinearmodelfit-or-fi)

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing, and the thing that can be easily missed is that the second argument of `Dynamic` must be a **function** or a list of functions:

```
list = {};
Slider[Dynamic[b, (b = #; list = Join[list, {b}]) &], {1, 10, 1}]
Dynamic@list
```

> [image]

Comment: Another thing that can be easily missed is that the second argument of `Dynamic` only seems to work reliably when the `Dynamic` expression is evaluated as an argument of a control or other GUI element (like the slider you used in your example). I have found that the front-end does seem to like a naked `Dynamic` with a 2nd argument when it encounters one at top-level such as in the example the OP gave.

Comment: @m_goldberg good point, I have not though he tried to do that this way. It seems I have to write a little bit more. :)

Comment: @m_goldberg: you say "only seems to work reliably", but does it work at all and is it supposed to? I would have said it most probably isn't even meant to work, but honestly don't know what actually is the "documented" behavior that I could expect. I also can't see that a naked `Dynamic` with a 2nd argument does anything relevant concerning its 2nd argument, other than quietly ignoring it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AlbertRetey. I used tentative language because I don't know for sure. From my reading of the docs and my own experiments, I think it likely that the 2nd argument of `Dynamic` is not intended to be used at top-level the way the OP of this question did. My experience with naked `Dynamic` is exactly as you say. BTW, there is a typo in my comment. I meant to say: "does **not** seem to like a naked `Dynamic`"

Comment: @AlbertRetey I agree with you, it's meant to cooperate with controllers: "during interactive changing or editing of val." I think that m_goldberg pointed that OP tried to use it in "naked" Dynamic. I'm waiting for confirmation from OP. :)

Comment: @AlbertRetey. Actually, I recant on the "exactly". In a few of my experiments with a naked `Dynamic` with a 2nd arg, I provoked the front-end to go into an infinite evaluation loop. And once I was able to crash the front-end.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I think the missing **not** makes my previous comment superfluos :-)